# How do I enable HTTP-DAV in Apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, webdav

I'm trying to enable HTTP-DAV on Apache (httpd.x86_64 2.2.3-43.el5.centos) running on CentOS 5.4.

I have the following relevant entries in my httpd.conf.

```
LoadModule dav_module modules/mod_dav.so
LoadModule dav_fs_module modules/mod_dav_fs.so

<IfModule mod_dav_fs.c>
    DAVLockDB /var/lib/dav/lockdb
</IfModule>

<Location /var/www/html/updates>
    Dav On
</Location>
```

`/var/www/html/` is the Apache root. I have reloaded Apache without any errors in the error log. I can also access this directory via HTTP in Firefox.

I have an application under development which needs to communicate with the web server over HTTP-DAV, but instead reports that the web server returned "(405) Method not allowed". This happens when it sends a PROPFIND request.

Apache's access log reports the following when that happens:

```
192.168.1.29 - - [25/Nov/2010:17:21:26 +0200] "PROPFIND /updates/2.0.1.0/ HTTP/1.1" 405 320 "-" "-"
```

Presumably HTTP-DAV isn't enabled. What am I doing wrong?

**Reply to pacey:** There are no `Limit` or `LimitExcept` Directives in any of Apache's configuration files. There is no .htaccess file in `/var/www/html/updates/` or `/var/www/html/`.

**Reply to Zoredache:** Apache has write access to updates.

**Reply to iiegn:** I gave cadaver a try. Apparently WebDAV's not enabled.

```
dav:!> open http://hybrid/updates/
Could not access /updates/ (not WebDAV-enabled?):
405 Method Not Allowed
Connection to `hybrid' closed.
```

The only relevant thing in the logs (LogLevel debug) is in the access log:

```
192.168.1.240 - - [26/Nov/2010:14:41:45 +0200] "OPTIONS /updates/ HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "cadaver/0.22.3 neon/0.25.5"
192.168.1.240 - - [26/Nov/2010:14:41:45 +0200] "PROPFIND /updates/ HTTP/1.1" 405 319 "-" "cadaver/0.22.3 neon/0.25.5"
```

Comment: are there any `<Limit>` or `LimitExcept` Directives in the apache configuration?

Comment: maybe the error log will tell you more?

Comment: Does the apache user have write access to /updates/?

Comment: is there a .htaccess file in the path to /var/www/html/updates which gets evaluated? If so, what are the contents.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally figured it out.

Instead of

```
<Location /var/www/html/updates>
    Dav On
</Location>
```

it needs to be (`Directory` instead of `Location`)

```
<Directory /var/www/html/updates>
   Dav On
</Directory>
```

Comment: hm, then there seems to be some interaction with, i guess, /var/www being DocRoot or other (Directory) settings further up the path. i have dav working on a <Location /some/path> with /some/path not being part of any other setting.

Comment: I have the same problem (405 error) but I am using Directory.

Comment: DAV will not work on a directory if DirectoryIndex is enabled and the index file exists (usually index.html). I guess the two situations require different responses for the same HTTP request.

Comment: This worked, but I don't understand why... The docs specify the use of mod_dav with Location tags... http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dav.html

Answer (score 1):

The set-up seems sufficient.

To test the set-up you could try [cadaver](http://www.webdav.org/cadaver/), the command-line WebDAV client for Unix. There, start with something like `"> open URL"` to see whether you can open a connection. Then, `"> propget ."` or `"> ls"`

...and with the `PROPFIND` request pay attention to: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dav.html#davdepthinfinity.